# Merging dataframes by column values in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'w':['a','b','c'], 'x':['d','e','f']})


df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'w':['b','a','g','c'], 'x':['h','d','i','f'],'y':['j','k','l','m'],'z':['n','o','p','q']})

In [106]: df1
Out[106]: 
   w  x
0  a  d
1  b  e
2  c  f

In[107]: df2
Out[107]: 
   w  x  y  z
0  b  h  j  n
1  a  d  k  o
2  g  i  l  p
3  c  f  m  q
```

Both dataframes have same columns df1 and df2. I need to add columns 'y' and 'z' on df2 to df1 such that the values in columns 'w' and 'x' are identical.

The end result would be:

```
  w  x  y  z
0 a  d  k  o
1 c  f  m  q
```

Comment: `df2` does not have `b` and `e` in `w` and `x` respectively. Can you explain their values in your end result?

Comment: Sorry,  I have edited my original post.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2)` gets your desired output if I understand correctly

Comment: @sacul, you are right! Thanks much!

Comment: @sacul, that is what my answer says. Still downvoted. :(

Comment: To be fair, you were downvoted when your result didn't match the desired result, then the question was edited.

Comment: @chrisz, I would wait for further clarification from now on from OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) .

```
df1.merge(df2)
```

Output :

```
    w   x   y   z
0   a   d   k   o
1   c   f   m   q
```